# How to remove Author's addresses in acm art?

Tags: acmart

In `acmart` template, I am trying to remove authors' addresses footnote which gets placed automatically in the first page. Here is a copy of this footnote:

```
Authors’ addresses: first_name last_name, University of California Davis, 1 Shields Ave, Davis, CA, 95616, USA, email@ucdavis.edu;
```

Can you please let me know how can I remove it?

Comment: For future reference, *always* include some form of code that the community can copy-and-paste to work on. It really helps if you help the community get on the same page as you are.

Comment: @Werner thank you for your comment. How do you expect me to write code here? Three lines of scripts that you kindly wrote below is all people need to add to the template. The question is self-explanatory and that along with your answer, in my view, can help many.

Comment: We expect you to write code like [this](https://pastebin.com/RNf9KcAA). It contains everything to replicate the issue without any additional fluff that isn't needed. It's called a [minimal, working example/MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). The idea is to [help others reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This might sound menial in this instance because 3 lines of code solved it, but it's a habit that proves worthwhile in general. Make it part of your repertoire.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call the document class with the `anonymous` option. However, this removes all identification of the author(s), printing the author(s) as `ANONYMOUS AUTHOR(S)`.

You can also just set a special macro to `\@empty`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@authorsaddresses\@empty
\makeatother
```

The above is used in a condition to check whether an author address is supplied. However, the entire footnote is set based on this condition, and therefore setting `\@authorsaddresses` to `\@empty` skips the process of setting the footnote containing the author credentials.

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\address{An address}
\email{who@cares.com}

\makeatletter
\let\@authorsaddresses\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to acmart document:

> [image: You can suppress printing authors’ addresses by setting them to an empty string: \authorsaddresses{}. Please note that authors’ addresses are mandatory for journal articles]

You can use instead to avoid `makeatletter`:

```tex
\authorsaddresses{}
```